# Core Data not saving NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsstring

Currently seeing an issue in my Core Data saving. For some reason a NSString isn't being saved properly, always returning 0 regardless. Below is my current code.

```
appDelegate =(NotaciousAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
        NSArray *fetchedNotes;

        NSArray *notes = [object valueForKey:@"result"];
        for (NSDictionary *singleNote in notes){

            noteFetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [noteFetch setEntity:entity];
            NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID==%@",[singleNote objectForKey:@"note id"]];
            [noteFetch setPredicate:pred];

            NSError *fetchError=nil;
            fetchedNotes=[appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:noteFetch error:&fetchError];

            if (fetchError!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"syncNotes fetchError=%@,details=%@",fetchError,fetchError.userInfo);
            }
            if ([fetchedNotes count]==0) {


                NSString *notelocked = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note locked"];

                NSString *notecreated = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note created"];
                NSString *noteupdated = [singleNote valueForKey:@"note updated"];
                NSString *notetitle = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note title"];
                NSString *notesummary = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note summary"];
                NSString *noteid = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note id"];
                NSString *notecontent = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note content"];

                NSString *formattedTitle = [NSString decodeShit:notetitle];
                NSString *formattedSummary = [NSString decodeShit:notesummary];
                NSString *formattedContent = [NSString decodeShit:notecontent];


                NSLog(@"Note Title: %@",formattedTitle);
                NSLog(@"Note Summary: %@",formattedSummary);
                NSLog(@"Note ID: %@",noteid);
                NSLog(@"Note Content: %@",formattedContent);
                NSLog(@"Note Created: %@",notecreated);
                NSLog(@"Note Updated: %@",noteupdated);
                NSLog(@"Note Locked: %@",notelocked);

                newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                [newNote autorelease];

                [newNote setValue:formattedContent forKey:@"content"];
                [newNote setValue:formattedSummary forKey:@"summary"];
                [newNote setValue:formattedTitle forKey:@"title"];
                [newNote setValue:noteid forKey:@"ID"];
                [newNote setValue:notecreated forKey:@"created"];
                [newNote setValue:noteupdated forKey:@"updated"];
                [newNote setValue:notelocked forKey:@"locked"];

                NSLog(@"Note Updated in MOC:%@",[newNote valueForKey:@"updated"]);

                NSError *error = nil;
                if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    abort();
                }


            }

            [noteFetch release];

        }
```

The issue arises when trying to save the *updated* string. For some reason, regardless of what string is in there, it will not save to the Core Data attribute.

I'm struggling to find any coherent reason for it to not be saving, but I'm about to deem it possible. This is the last issue that needs to be sorted before this application can hit the shelves. Any help would be great!

**Edit**

There is no error, only the following output in the debug console.

```
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.815 Notacious[5660:707] Note Title: Hello there!
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.816 Notacious[5660:707] Note Summary: 
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.817 Notacious[5660:707] Note ID: 1240
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.817 Notacious[5660:707] Note Content: Hello there!

 This is a new note made from the iPhone client. Woot?
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.818 Notacious[5660:707] Note Created: Thu Apr 21 19:19:39 -0700 2011
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.819 Notacious[5660:707] Note Updated: Thu Apr 21 19:19:39 -0700 2011
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.820 Notacious[5660:707] Note Locked: 0
 2011-04-24 10:53:22.823 Notacious[5660:707] Note Updated in MOC:0
```

Comment: Do you see anything come up in error?

Comment: Added the output from the console to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has worked.

```
appDelegate =(NotaciousAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
        NSArray *fetchedNotes;

        NSArray *notes = [object valueForKey:@"result"];
        for (NSDictionary *singleNote in notes){

            noteFetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [noteFetch setEntity:entity];
            NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID==%@",[singleNote objectForKey:@"note id"]];
            [noteFetch setPredicate:pred];

            NSError *fetchError=nil;
            fetchedNotes=[appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:noteFetch error:&fetchError];

            if (fetchError!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"syncNotes fetchError=%@,details=%@",fetchError,fetchError.userInfo);
            }
            if ([fetchedNotes count]==0) {

                NSString *notelocked = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note locked"];

                NSString *noteupdated = [singleNote valueForKey:@"note updated"];
                NSString *notecreated = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note created"];
                NSString *notetitle = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note title"];
                NSString *notesummary = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note summary"];
                NSString *noteid = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note id"];
                NSString *notecontent = [singleNote objectForKey:@"note content"];

                NSString *formattedTitle = [NSString decodeShit:notetitle];
                NSString *formattedSummary = [NSString decodeShit:notesummary];
                NSString *formattedContent = [NSString decodeShit:notecontent];

                newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

                [newNote setValue:formattedContent forKey:@"content"];
                [newNote setValue:formattedSummary forKey:@"summary"];
                [newNote setValue:formattedTitle forKey:@"title"];
                [newNote setValue:noteid forKey:@"ID"];
                [newNote setValue:notecreated forKey:@"created"];
                [newNote setValue:noteupdated forKey:@"noteupdated"];
                [newNote setValue:notelocked forKey:@"locked"];

                NSError *error = nil;
                if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    abort();
                }


            }

            [noteFetch release];

        }
```

It seems that CoreData didn't like me accessing an attribute with the name `updated`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure "note updated" in the dictionary is not an NSDate instead of an NSString?  The log output makes it look an AWFUL lot like you have an NSDate in there.

You would need to use an NSDateFormatter to save it into an NSString object property if so.

Comment: That is true that it is an NSDate. However, another weird thing is going on, how come the "note created" is able to be saved and not the "note updated". They're both NSStrings being stored into two different NSString attributes...

Comment: I'm not sure why that works but I'm pretty sure that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Alright, will update to include an NSDateFormatter so I can save the string properly. Will get back to you.

Comment: Did the above and still nothing is being saved.

Comment: Hmm, sorry - not sure what else to try.  You might try running "mogenerator" on your object model to see if it has any validation warnings.  That's a third party tool you have to download.